# Getting associated trade agreement (PriceDiscAdmTrans) from a record in SalesLine table in dynamics ax

Tags: axapta

How do I get the associated record in trade agreement journal (PriceDiscAdmTrans) from the record in SalesLine Table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no associated `PriceDiscAdmTrans` record to a `SalesLine`.

There may be an associated `PriceDiscTable` record to a `SalesLine`, but the rules to find it is defined by workings of `SalesPurchLine::setPriceAgreement` and the `PriceDisc` class.

Answer (score 0):

When a PriceDiscAdmTrans is posted in PriceDiscAdmCheckPost it will create a PriceDiscTable which a salesLine may use to determine the discount via the PriceDisc classes